# Oracle 11g Selecting from N to 1 table to a common table to an 1 to N table, with a restriction

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

### Problem

I have these tables and data:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    id   NUMBER(3) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE a ADD CONSTRAINT a_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id );

CREATE TABLE b (
    id   NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    year NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    a_id NUMBER(3) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE b ADD CONSTRAINT b_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id );

CREATE TABLE c (
    id         NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
    start_date DATE NOT NULL,
    end_date   DATE NOT NULL,
    a_id       NUMBER(3) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE c ADD CONSTRAINT c_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id );

ALTER TABLE b
    ADD CONSTRAINT b_a_fk FOREIGN KEY ( a_id )
        REFERENCES a ( id );

ALTER TABLE c
    ADD CONSTRAINT c_a_fk FOREIGN KEY ( a_id )
        REFERENCES a ( id );

Insert into A (ID) values ('1');
Insert into A (ID) values ('2');
Insert into A (ID) values ('3');

Insert into B (ID,YEAR,A_ID) values ('1','2017','1');
Insert into B (ID,YEAR,A_ID) values ('2','2017','2');
Insert into B (ID,YEAR,A_ID) values ('3','2013','3');
Insert into B (ID,YEAR,A_ID) values ('4','2014','3');
Insert into B (ID,YEAR,A_ID) values ('5','2017','3');
Insert into B (ID,YEAR,A_ID) values ('6','2013','1');

Insert into C (ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,A_ID) values ('1',to_date('01/01/13','DD/MM/RR'),to_date('01/01/14','DD/MM/RR'),'3');
Insert into C (ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,A_ID) values ('2',to_date('01/06/17','DD/MM/RR'),to_date('01/01/18','DD/MM/RR'),'3');
Insert into C (ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,A_ID) values ('3',to_date('01/01/14','DD/MM/RR'),to_date('01/06/14','DD/MM/RR'),'3');
Insert into C (ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,A_ID) values ('4',to_date('01/01/17','DD/MM/RR'),to_date('01/10/17','DD/MM/RR'),'1');
Insert into C (ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,A_ID) values ('5',to_date('01/04/13','DD/MM/RR'),to_date('01/10/13','DD/MM/RR'),'1');
Insert into C (ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,A_ID) values ('6',to_date('01/01/17','DD/MM/RR'),to_date('01/06/18','DD/MM/RR'),'2');
```

I need for each B: B.id, A.id and C.id, where C is the first oldest start_date row where B.year is in between C.start_date and C.end_date, like this:

```
BID AID CID
1   1   4
2   2   6
3   3   1
4   3   3
5   3   2
6   1   5
```

Please help me with an answer or a where to find the information to do this.

I know the nested select doesn't recognize the outside table A, but I don't know how to make a working solution for this or I'm missing something very simple; I don't know. I hope you can help me.

### Solution

I had something like this with the help of the community:

```
select B.id BID, A.id AID, C.id CID
from B
    join A on B.A_id = A.id
    join C
    on C.A_id = A.id 
where B.year between extract (year from C.start_date) and extract(year from C.end_date)
order by B.id ASC , c.start_date asc;
```

It returned:

```
BID AID CID
1   1   4
2   2   6
3   3   1
4   3   1
4   3   3
5   3   2
6   1   5
```

But the real answer was:

```
select bid, aid, cid
from
  (select B.id bid, A.id aid, C.id cid, 
               row_number() over (partition by b.id order by c.start_date) rn
          from B
          join A on B.A_id = A.id
          join c on C.A_id = A.id
           and B.year between extract(year from c.start_date) 
                          and extract(year from c.end_date))
where rn = 1;
```

That returns what I was searching for.

Thanks to all, specially to Ponder Stibbons, that gave me the way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build `join`, number rows and take only first row for each `id`:

```
select bid, aid, cid 
  from (select B.id bid, A.id aid, C.id cid, 
               row_number() over (partition by c.a_id order by b.year) rn
          from B
          join A on B.A_id = A.id
          join c on C.A_id = A.id
           and B.year between extract(year from c.start_date) 
                          and extract(year from c.end_date))
  where rn = 1;
```

Test:

```
create table a (id number(3));
create table b (id number(6), year number(4), a_id   number(3));
create table c (id number(9), start_date date, end_date date, a_id  number(3));

insert into a values (1);
insert into a values (2);

insert into b values (1, 1901, 1);
insert into b values (2, 1905, 1);
insert into b values (3, 1903, 1);
insert into b values (4, 1902, 2);

insert into c values (1, date '1902-01-01', date '1912-07-17', 1);
insert into c values (2, date '1900-02-18', date '1910-06-08', 2);
```

Result:

```
    BID  AID        CID
------- ---- ----------
      3    1          1
      4    2          2
```

Comment: I want to retrieve every B.

Comment: Ty for responding, I didn't know about extract

Comment: I modified partition by c.a_id to b.id and it worked (I need to read about partitions a little bit).
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many issues with your DDLs and the query.

Avoid oracle reserved keywords for column names. The one with `end` as column name will never run.

```
year   NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
start     DATE NOT NULL,
end       DATE NOT NULL,
```

Instead use something like `year_t,start_t, end_t` or something that is meaningful.

> I want to do a select with B.id, A.id and C.id where C is the first
>   row where B.year is in between C.start and C.end, for every B.

You don't do it using `and rownum < 1`. In fact `rownum < 1` will never return any rows.

The column names you are using are also wrong. For eg: there is no `b.start` which you use in your `order by` .

So,considering those changes This query will work.

```
select B.id, A.id, C.id
from B
    join A on B.A_id = A.id
    join C
    on C.A_id = A.id 
where B.year_t between to_number(to_char(C.start_t, 'YYYY')) and to_number(to_char(C.end_t, 'YYYY')) 
            order by c.start_t,B.id ASC ;
```

But, it won't give you

> the first row where B.year is in between C.start and C.end, for every
>   B

Clarify with data as to what exactly do you need in the question with some sample records. then i will try to answer.

Comment: It very good. I clarified it a little more. Your answer is very close. But it duplicates bid = 4 because there is two C ids that conform with B.year between C.start_date and C.end_date. I just want to retrieve the one with the oldest start_date.